# PostgreSQL rules in Azure automation

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-automation, azure-postgresql

For a business case where I’m working on now I have a problem. I have A device which has to write on an Azure PostgreSQL server (https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/services/postgresql/). The device has a dynamic DNS (creating a network or something like that is not an option).

My first thought was creating an Azure automation runbook who adds a firewall rule to the PostgreSQL server. I created the first couple of lines which extracts the IP from the DNS but there seems not a option to create a firewall rule for PostgreSQL.

Code:

```
$ips = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("dynamicdns.example.net")
$regex = [regex] "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
$ip2 = $regex.Matches($ips) | %{ $_.value }
```

Does anyone know A solution to automate the update of the PostgreSQL firewall so this don’t be a manual job anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish the requirement to create a new firewall rule or update an existing firewall rule for PostgreSQL by leveraging [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/postgresql/firewallrules/createorupdate) REST API. You may call the REST API from Azure Automation PowerShell runbook with the help of [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7) cmdlet.

Ideally you would get array of IP's after your first 3 lines of code that was provided. You may have to develop code to call the above mentioned REST API in loop to add all the retrieved array of IP's.